# JQuery ScrollTo not working with Height and Width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen this question asked on here before but with no working answers, also I imagine my problem is slightly different.

I have got quite a strange issue which I have been trying to work out, I am fairly sure I have not structured my css correctly but am having issues finding out where.

If you look at the following template in jsfiddle (ignore broken images)

## [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/AKkjR/)

The height and width of the body is not scrolling, the scrollbar does appear down the right side but is unscrollable (am using a custom scrollbar). I realise this is to do with the body not inheriting a height most likely due to my floating div's.

I have been playing around with a clearfix div which I am still trying to make work, understandably if I add

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

to my css for my body class the scroll will work, however if I do this the JQuery ScrollTo stops working

I have put the `anchor-link` which does the scrollto in the top of this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HUfbv/) (it is also in the above fiddle but is not visible on the page and scrolling is broken)

Understandably I need to clean up my code, but any advice on how I can get out of this situation would be just awesome!

Please let me know if I have not explained very well
Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I was being a giant numpty, slightly embarrassing but found the following in the middle of my css:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is certainly what was causing the problem, issue solved!